# .htaccess of symfony make a 302 redirection

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, redirect

Using symfony for my website and i have a 302 redirection from my https://www.exemple.com/ to https://www.exemple.com/, and google doesn't want 302 redirection... It is the last condition of the rewrite section of the .htaccess which does that.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried to put instead :

```
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [R=301,L]
```

But in that case i have a 301 redirection but my site is not reachable. Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you the apache module `mod_rewrite` enabled? What you described is the behaviour when is not enabled...

Comment: Hi @Matteo and thank you for helping. Yes mod_rewrite seems to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Find solution,

It was not the .htaccess in cause. I'm new with 301/302 redirection and didn't know u can spécifiate it in controller. So i add a ",301" at the end of redirections i do in controller like that :

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sdzbikind_acceuil'), 301);
```

Hope it helps somebody else... I'm just asking now if i should do 301 redirection in all my symfony project redirections !?